# Ag grid delete row and update table

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I created a separate component with delete functionality for ag grid. On clicking the delete button, the delete method received that single row data and I was able to make a the delete call. Now how can I update the table after deleting? I was thinking instead of making an api call again to backend to fetch data again if I can just filter out the deleted row from table and send it back to table. But how can I do that since I am in a separate component where I do not have the whole table data but just one row data?

HTML

```
<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    domLayout='autoHeight'
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Code for buttonRenderer Component

```
public onDelete = async ($event) => {
  if ((await this.teamService.deleteTeamMember(this.params.node.data._id)) === false) 
{
  return;
}
  this.notification.success('Team member deleted successfully.');
//this.team = this.team.filter((item) => item._id !== customer._id);
};
```

Grid Component

```
this.gridOptions = {
        suppressMenuHide: false,
        columnDefs: [
        { headerName: 'Name', field: 'fullName', width: 150, sortable: true, filter: true },
        { headerName: 'Email', field: 'email', width: 170, sortable: true, filter: true, tooltipField: 'email'},
        {
          suppressMovable: true,
          headerName: 'Status',
          width: 100,
          field: 'disabled', cellRenderer: (params) => 
          params.data.disabled === false ? `<img src="assets/images/check.svg">` : `<img src="assets/images/minus.svg">`
        },
        { 
          headerName: 'Last Login', 
          field: 'lastLoginDate', 
          sortable: true, 
          filter: true,
          cellRenderer: (params) => params.data.lastLoginDate ? 
          new Date(params.data.lastLoginDate).toISOString().split('T')[0] + 
          `<img src="assets/images/clock.svg">` +
          new Date(params.data.lastLoginDate).toISOString().split('T')[1] : ``
        },
        {
          headerName: 'Created',
          width: 130,
          field: 'dateCreated',
          cellRenderer: (params) => new Date(params.data.dateCreated).toISOString().split('T')[0],
          sortable: true, 
          filter: true
        },
        {
          cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
          cellRendererParams: {
            onClick: this.onBtnClick1.bind(this),
            label: 'Click 1'
          }
        },
       ],
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a simple table, that is a table that doesn't have virtual scrolling or lazy loading implemented. You could try splicing the deleted record from the `rowData` using its index as soon as the function to delete record from table has been invoked and then set the rows into the grid again after splicing.

You can leverage the grid API for achieving this as demonstrated in the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-button-renderer-ch6tbx?file=src/app/app.component.html) project.

Comment: I am not sure where I can use this `gridOptions.api.setRowData(gridOptions.rowData)` because you see the button rendering is a separate component. I followed this example on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-button-renderer?file=src%2Fapp%2Frenderer%2Fbutton-renderer.component.ts

Comment: I have updated my answer and added link to a project where the button is being created as a separate component using `Cell Renderer`. Also, I noticed that in your `component.html` file where the ag-Grid table has been defined you are not adding event binding for the `gridReady` event.

Answer (score 3):

As the api call succeed, you can just update/delete/add using:-

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/data-update-transactions/

```
this.gridApi?.applyTransaction({ remove: [{ id: rowId }] });
```